# formatting a string in python based on pixels

Tags: python

I am reading an xml file in python and then displaying it on a web gui
The reading code is pretty straightforward

```
def home ():
    file = "sample.xml"
    contents = open(file).read()
    contents = contents.decode('utf-8')
```

And then there is whole lot of front end code consisting of html and css...

But... to display it.. I want that the each line doesnt exceeds say 200px??

i.e insert a newline(??) after n pixels..

How can I do this in python..

Comment: Well, what is a line - what is the pixel size on the user's browser(s)? etc... etc...

Comment: ? what is inside your xml? Why do you think you can render it to pixels?

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS to style the output?

Comment: This is at best a CSS with "overflow" typing - not a Python question - I've voted to close

Comment: Thanks for the input.. but lets say I want to handle it on python end and not on css end.. lets say i am outputing it on terminal and dont want to exceed certain width area on my terminal.. how do i solve it then?

Comment: Your terminal is not pixel-based; it's character-based. Your best bet would be to check the `COLUMNS` environment variable, and limit your output string length to that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the access to the font file you are using, you can use a lib like freetype for loading the font glyph data. That allows you to calculate the width of a text string.

There are several resources for doing this in python, [freetype-py](https://github.com/davidcox/freetype-py) is one of them. It contains some examples to look at.
Also see [freetype lib](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/) for the documentation.